# Using "data-*" attributes to replace the "id" attributes in HTML tags for CSS-Selecting Purpose

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Is it a good idea to use "data-" attributes to replace the "id" attributes in elements(tags) for css-selection purposes and then use those "data-*" attributes in automation testing scripts?

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Answer (score 4):

No.

CSS selection and DOM-tree selection on id is much faster than selection any other attribute. Data-attribute select might be less efficient than selection on other attributes in somebrowsers.

The exception might be if you are abusing id attributes: storing something that is not just an identifier in them (e.g. composite data or something not unique).  Selecting parts of id values, if supported,  gives terrible performance.  I would recommend using data attributes over abusing id attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Factually, you can use any of the attributes of an element.

So, **Yes**, you can use **`data-*`** attribute instead of **`id`** attribute as well provided the element is uniquely identified.

---

### [HTML data-* Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

- The `data-*` attributes are used to store custom data private to the page or application.
- The `data-*` attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.
- The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or server-side database queries).
- The `data-*` attributes consist of two parts:

  - The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix `data-`
  - The attribute value can be any string
- Note: Custom attributes prefixed with `data-` will be completely ignored by the user agent.

Comment: The question is, "Is it a good idea?" not "Can it be done?" and it's off topic altogether.