# How would one use data-* attributes to replace id in practice?

Tags: html, css

I know, thanks to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053324/using-data-attributes-to-replace-the-id-attributes-in-html-tags-for-css-se), that this is *not* a good idea but is, apparently, possible.  But I'm in a situation where the CMS automatically strips any `id=`selectors, and I'm trying to find a workaround.  (**Unfortunately, no JS; any solutions need to be strictly CSS and HTML.**)

But, I'm completely new to the idea of data-* attributes, and I'm uncomfortable trying to figure this out on my own, since my own unfamiliarity with how they work isn't conducive to doing it right.

So, here's the question.  Say I wanted to recreate something like the CSS :target tabs in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/MarekZeman91/pen/wBwbrp.

Is it *possible* to replace the id selectors with data-* attributes?  And if so, how would I go about doing it?  Not just for the example, but in general.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to replace all elements with an id of `X` with an attribute of `data-X`, eg

```
<div id="tabs">
```

will turn into

```
<div data-tabs>
```

Once you've changed the HTML, you then need to:

(1) Change the CSS. The selector string for an ID is `#id`; the selector string for an element with a particular attribute is `[attributeName]`. So `#tabs` will turn into `[data-tabs]`. Replace all instances of `#tabs` with `[data-tabs]`.

Keep in mind that ID selectors have a very high specificity compared to attribute selectors. If the elements you're targeting are matched by multiple clashing CSS rules, changing the ID to an attribute may result in the wrong rule winning, so you might have to change things a bit more until all the rules get applied as expected.

(2) Change the Javascript. Just like above, use the selector string `[data-tabs]` wherever you used to have `#tabs`, eg:

```
var link = document.querySelector('#tabs > .tab-link');
```

turns into

```
var link = document.querySelector('[data-tabs] > .tab-link');
```

You can repeat the above pattern for all IDs present, until none are left.

---

You can also consider using classes instead, they work just as well, eg change

```
<div id="tabs">
```

to

```
<div class="tabs">
```

and then use the selector string `.tabs` everywhere instead of `#tabs`.

Comment: It was step #2 that was tripping me up.  So there's no way to accomplish that without Javascript?

Comment: If the Javascript requires using a particular ID, and you remove the ID, and you can't change the Javascript, that section of Javascript (or more) will stop working.